# When is/was the 2021 Formula 1 champion officially decided?

Tags: formula-1

After the final 2021 race in Abu Dhabi, post-race protests were thrown out and it is now being reported that Max Verstappen is the drivers' world champion.

Is this *technically* correct? Or is the champion officially decided at some later date, a bit like how the US has president-elect between the election result and the inauguration?

Is this formally described anywhere? Of course, results can theoretically be overturned later but that is a different matter.

Answer (score 3):

Formula 1 *officially* crowns the Championship winner and other awards, like the Constructors Championship, at the [FIA Prize Giving Ceremony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIA_Prize_Giving_Ceremony).

This event is usually held the Thursday after the last race of the season. For the 2021 season, this is Thursday 16th December, and is set to be held at Le Louvre in Paris.

The reason crowning the Champion it is delayed is because, as we have seen in the 2021 Abu Dhabi race, there may be a number of challenges, stewards decisions, rule infringements etc. that could alter the outcome of the race, and indeed the Championship.

Though as you say, and in particular with this case, there is still potential for the results to change via the Court of Arbitration for Sport.